# Sum of all n dimensional spheres?

Tags: summation, gamma-function, area

I was messing around and made some code to find the area of an  *n*  dimensional sphere.  I noticed that as  *n*  increases, the area tends towards zero.  These were the results:

```
area of 1 dimensional sphere: 2.0001751221664
area of 2 dimensional sphere: 3.1415926535898
area of 3 dimensional sphere: 4.189156979794
area of 4 dimensional sphere: 4.9348022005447
area of 5 dimensional sphere: 5.2642499169821
area of 6 dimensional sphere: 5.16771278005
area of 7 dimensional sphere: 4.7251796759576
area of 8 dimensional sphere: 4.0587121264168
area of 9 dimensional sphere: 3.2987977237512
area of 10 dimensional sphere: 2.5501640398773
area of 11 dimensional sphere: 1.8842688535664
area of 12 dimensional sphere: 1.3352627688546
area of 13 dimensional sphere: 0.91070849042345
area of 14 dimensional sphere: 0.59926452932079
area of 15 dimensional sphere: 0.38147668041015
area of 16 dimensional sphere: 0.23533063035889
area of 17 dimensional sphere: 0.14099345137557
area of 18 dimensional sphere: 0.082145886611128
area of 19 dimensional sphere: 0.046625683267975
area of 20 dimensional sphere: 0.025806891390014
```

The function to find the area of an  *n*  dimensional sphere is:

$$f(n) = \frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma{(1 + \frac{n}{2})}}$$

where  *n*  is the dimension.  How would I calculate the sum of all  *n*  dimensional spheres?

Comment: Maple gives the answer as $-1+2e^\pi-e^\pi{\rm erfc}(\sqrt\pi)$.

Comment: Mathematica says the sum is $e^\pi(1+\mbox{erf}(\sqrt{\pi}))-1$, where erf$(z)$ is the error function $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^z e^{-t^2}\,dt$.

Comment: use summation with n -> 0 to infinity. Question what do you mean by sum of all n dimensonal spheres? Area or what?

Comment: There seems to be something amiss---surely the volume of the $1$-ball should be exactly $2$.

Comment: what is a one dimensional sphere anyway? I thought spheres were 3d and circles 2d. This is going to mess with my mind

Comment: What is 5d sphere anyway if 4d sphere is interior of 3-sphere

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/N_SpheresVolumeAndSurfaceArea.png - this explained it to me.

Comment: The sum of all n-dimensional hyper-cubes: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n~=~\dfrac1{1-x}$$ The sum of all n-dimensional straight-edged pyramids: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}~=~e^x$$

Comment: @Travis Yeah, it's not exact due to floating point and wherever rounding may have occured